# errors parsing go.mod How to deploy go app on App Engine with Cloud build?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-build

So I have this Go app which is running fine on the localhost but I want to host on the google cloud and the cloud is already setup. The whole dir tree looks like this.

```
gocode
---bin
---pkg
---src
  ---cloud.google.com
  ---github.com
  ...
  ---appname
    ---auth
    ---database
    ...
    ---main.go
    ---app.yaml
    ---cloudbuild.yaml
    ---go.mod
```

Here is the **app.yaml**

```
runtime: go112
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Here is the **cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:

- name: 'golang'
  args: ['go', 'build', '.']
  env: ['GO111MODULE=on']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['get', '-d', 'appname']
  env: ['GOPATH=/gopath/','MODE=dev']
  volumes:
  - name: 'go'
    path: '/gopath'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
  env: ['GOPATH=/gopath/','MODE=dev']
  volumes:
  - name: 'go'
    path: '/gopath'
```

Here is the **go.mod**

```
module github.com/Raj-Varun/appname-API/

require github.com/spf13/viper
```

When I'm running `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .` I'm getting this error

```
tarting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: golang
Step #0: Using default tag: latest
Step #0: latest: Pulling from library/golang
Step #0: Digest: sha256:a50a9364e9170ab5f5b03389ed33b9271b4a7b6bbb0ab41c4035adb3078927bc
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:latest
Step #0: docker.io/library/golang:latest
Step #0: go: errors parsing go.mod:
Step #0: /workspace/go.mod:3: usage: require module/path v1.2.3
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "golang" failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: What's your `go.mod` file?

Comment: I have messed up! I know! Can you tell me this thing when I'm trying to build the app I'm getting this error from the main.go `cannot load appname/auth: cannot find module providing package appname/auth`

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the error message, the require package path must have this format `require module/path v1.2.3`

In your go.mod, you have this:

```
require github.com/spf13/viper
```

You have the `module/path` but you don't have the version!

[Go the the viper github project and take the release version that you want](https://github.com/spf13/viper/releases). For example

```
require github.com/spf13/viper v1.4.0
```

You can also try to perform a `go mod tidy` for automatically building and cleaning your `go.mod` file

Comment: As a final step, you can also run `go mod verify` to check that all the dependencies are installed correctly.